# Почему не обновляется интерфейс после удаления элемента из массива angular

Tags: массивы, angular

```
 this.favoritFilms = this.favoritFilms.filter(
        (el) => el.id !== filmElement.id
      );
```

Был элемент, стерся.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но шаблон не поменялся[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Сделал через splice, заработало

```
 const ind = this.favoritFilms.findIndex((el) => el.id === filmElement.id);
  this.favoritFilms.splice(ind, 1);
```